# Reporting server: Server Error in '/Reports' Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to setup SQL Reporting services on windows vista, iis7 but I keep getting this error when I try http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

> ### Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
>
> Request is not available in this context  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.  Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context
>   Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.   Stack Trace:  [HttpException (0x80004005):
>   Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request()
>   +3465893    Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.get_ConfigurationManager()
>   +47    Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.GlobalApp.Application_Start(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +32 [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not
>   available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app)
>   +3385130    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +125
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
>   +182    System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context)
>   +259    System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +245 [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available
>   in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +3465475 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +69
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +675

The event viewer shows me something like this:

> 3005     An unhandled exception has occurred.     10/30/2008 12:31:56
>   PM     10/30/2008 9:31:56 AM     d6764b0e70d246a590d9a9e8186ef677
>   2     1     0     /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Reports-8-128698327158150000
>   RosettaMgr     /Reports     c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.4\Reporting Services\ReportManager\     
>           4756     w3wp.exe     NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE     HttpException     Request is not available in this context
>   http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
>   /Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx     ::1 
>           False 
>           NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE     5     NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE     False     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3459824&SiteID=1 - looks like someone had the same issue and was able to resolve it.